# SQL Server Implicit Order

Tags: sql, sql-server

i've got an issue due to database conception.

My data are grouped in a table which looks like :

```
IdGroup | IdValue
```

So for each group i've got the list of value.

Indeed, we should have had an order column or an id, but i can't.

Do you know anyway which can prove the order of the select value based on the insert order ?

I mean, if I inserted 1003,1001,1002 could i garantuee it to be retrieve in this order ?

```
IdGroup | IdValue
1       | 1003
1       | 1001
1       | 1002
```

Of course, using an order by doesn't seems to fit because i don't have any column usable.

Any idea ? Using a system proc or something like this.

Thanks a lot :)

Stop telling me to use an order by and altering the table, it doesn't fit and yes i know it's the good pratice to do... thanks :)

Comment: Does table has an index or indexes?

Comment: nope :/ but it's not a bad idea at all.

Comment: then unfortunately @Andrew and @Mitch are right, if you have database Recovery Model set to full, you can get proper insert order from this log but i've never used it...

Comment: @ykatchou - people are telling you to use `ORDER BY` because it's the *only* solution available. It's not "good practice", it's the only way to solve your problem.

Comment: My question is just to know if they're is another solution even tricky. Using log file is one of them (but this one is not fitting).

Comment: -1 for saying "Stop telling me to use an order by and altering the table". This is the SQL standard: respect it.

Comment: I know it's sql standard. I use it everyday, but if you're working in the real world, sometime you don't have the choice. I don't intend to use it, but it's more cultural. the bug doesn't worth to alter the database either to use an exotic way ! So i use to ask for which exotic way exist, not a way to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of ideas:

DBCC PAGE (undocumented) can be used to look at the raw data pages of the table.  It may be possible to determine insert order by looking at the low level information.

If you cannot alter the table, can you add a table to the database?  If so, consider creating a table with an identity column and use a trigger on the original table to insert the records in the new table.

Also, you should include which version(s) of SQL Server are involved.  Doing anything this unusual will very often be version specific.

Comment: "If you cannot alter the table, can you add a table to the database? If so, consider creating a table with an identity column and use a trigger on the original table to insert the records in the new table." I thought about this but can't too. It's on SQL Server 2008 R2. I'll look around DBCC PAGE. :)

Comment: dbcc page will not be able to give you the insert order unless no adjustments had ever been made, as soon as a row is deleted / inserted, then dbcc page could show the wrong order of insertion. Uniquifier or the transaction log would be the step to find that.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst some small scale tests will show that it returns it in what appears to be the right order, it just will not hold.

The golden rule remains - unless an order by clause is specified, there are no guarentees provided on the order of the returned data.

edit : If you place a non-clustered index on the idgroup column it is forced to add a hidden field, the uniqueifier since the values are the same - the problem it, you can't access it in an order by clause, but from a forensic perspective, you can determine the order it was inserted in.

Comment: I know but i don't have the choice :/

Comment: @ykatchou - you're choices at the moment are that you tell whoever requested this requirement that it cannot be achieved from the current schema, or you alter the schema. There aren't any other magical options.

Comment: i know, i was hoping there is some system proc which can do the magic tricks :) it seems it'll stay like this.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't rely on the data being returned in a particular order; use an `ORDER BY` clause to guarantee the order.

(Despite the fact that data appears to be returned in clustered index order, this might not always be the case).

Comment: I totally know this ! but i have to work with something already in prod :/

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the only way to guarantee an ordering is with an `ORDER BY` clause. What isn't highlighted in their answers is that, the only place that this `ORDER BY` matters is *in the `SELECT` statement*. It doesn't* matter if you apply an `ORDER BY` clause during the `INSERT` statement; the system is free to return results from a select in whatever order it finds most efficient, unless an `ORDER BY` is specified at that time.

*There's a particular way to ensure what order `IDENTITY` values are assigned to a result set during an `INSERT`, using an `ORDER BY`, but I can't remember the exact details, and it still doesn't effect the order of `SELECT`.

Comment: I totally agree with you ! But i don't have the choice at all. I just discover this bug, and the bug doesn't worth the risk of editing the database structure.

Comment: @Mitch - I've seen some people apply `ORDER BY` to their `INSERT` statements, in the vain hope that that would somehow affect later `SELECT` results...

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever : Yikes!!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - they may be trying to guarantee identity assignment, which is guaranteed when applying order by to an insert: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/07/20/441053.aspx

Comment: @SimonD - that's what my last paragraph was alluding to.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - understood, thought the link to the details would help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the **Created Date** column? In this way you can get the records using **Order by Clause** Created Date. Moreover set it's **default** value **Getdate()**

Comment: Then, You should at least have the Primary key, to get the data Order by Primary Key.